# Regular expression in bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a simple bookmaklet that takes a template and fills it asking the user for the appropriate values. Then that template is inserted into the active text input element. But the boorkmarklet I'm getting is unresponsive.

Here is the plain javascript text (for testing):

```
var template="Dear ${Customer} please put your ideas inside ${hole};"
alert(fillTemplate(template));

function fillTemplate(template) {
    var result = template;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${Column name}
    var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{[^\}]+\}/g);
    if (!templateVars) {
        return result;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
     var variableData = prompt("Please give a value for "+templateVars[i])
     result = result.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
   }

     return result;
};
```

The code above works as expected, but it does not when turned into bookmarklet. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the definition for `fillTemplate` first, before you call it. You should also consider putting the whole thing in an IIFE closure `;(function(){ ... })()` so the document itself doesn't end up with a `fillTemplate` method

Comment: This works for me as is in Chrome 39 and Firefox 33. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Dear Rhumborl, I though about that and I tried both, but still not working. I will check it again otherwise. But at least the template declaration should be before the function declaration.

Comment: Dear Rhumborl, I checked again your suggestion and it worked. I did not changed anything else. I don't know what I did wrong when I tried before. If you want to publish an answer I will accept it. Regards.